# Trans-universality for finite-dimensional Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, metric-spaces, banach-algebras

In addition to a specific problem [Trans-universality for finitely generated groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455591/trans-universality-for-finitely-generated-groups), I posted also its general form. It should not hurt to provide another special case:

**QUESTION**: does there exist a Banach space U such that the following three conditions hold:

- (a) every finite-dimensional Banach space is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of U;
- (b) for every Banach space G that is not finite-dimensional there exists a Banach space H that is generated by G and one additional element x, and such that H is not isometrically isomorphic to any subspace of U;
- (c) U is separable.

(***End** of Question*)

---

---

---

---

**Remark:**   A harder case would be that of Banach algebras
$\ C(X)\ $ over compact spaces $\ X$.

---

---

---

---

**About condition (b):**

A **”universal space”** peacefully combines contradictory logical tensions. Given a hederitary class $C$ of spaces, one tries to construct a (universal) space $U$ that contains an isomorphic image of every space $\ X\in C.\ $ The condition *hederitary* may mean something like “the class $C$ contains all closed subsets of members of $C$”, or similar. This roughly means that a universal space is *large*.

On the other hand, there must be a condition that tells us that the universal space is in a sense *small*. In the most classical cases (Urysohn, Sierpiński, Tikhonov, Menger, Hurewicz, ...), the universal space is small because it has to belong to the class $C$ itself: a universal space is large among small spaces (and it is one of them).

But in some problems (like the one in this question), the universal space cannot be a member of the original class $C$… Then what? We still need a condition ensuring that the universal space is small in some sense. In different cases, there have been different *smallness* conditions that depended ad hoc on the particular theory at the hand.

However, in 1961-62 I introduced a regular *smallness* condition that may apply to a variety of theories, even in cases where $U$ cannot belong to $\ C\ $: we assume that $U$ doesn't contain any abudant space that doesn't belong to C, except for the necessary ones (since, for instance, $U$ itself doesn't belong to $C$). Hence my condition (b).

Comment: I assume the Gurarij space doesn't satisfy (b)? Also, what is the motivation for (b)?

Comment: @JamesHanson Gurarij space is isometrically universal for separable Banach spaces. I wonder the motivation for (b) myself.

Comment: Szankowski's reflexive space satisfies (a) & (c). I don't know if it satisfies (b). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02789321

Comment: @JamesHanson and Onur Oktay I'll insert a very short mini-micro-intro about (b) into my ***Question***.

Comment: Nice question. Here is a related problem: Does there exist a Banach space $X$ that is isometrically universal for two dimensional spaces, but every two dimensional space is contained in a three dimensional space that does not embed isometrically into $X$? Maybe $L^1$ is such a space.

Comment: @BillJohnson, Great! Long live *universal space* theme! ######## It'd be good if you posted your quesion in a separate MO-thread.

Comment: @BillJohnson, does $L^1$ contain isometrically an euclidean plain? (f not then it's not universal for 2-d spaces).

Comment: Yes, Lindenstrauss proved that $L^1$ contains isometric copies of every $2$ dimensional space. For the Euclidean plane, you don't need Lindenstrauss' theorem: consider the span of two independent standard Gaussian random variables.

Comment: @BillJohnson looks so: a unit ball of the section of $L^1$ is a dual zonotope. 3d zonotope can not have a triangular facet (facets are Minkowski sums of segments), thus the dual body can not have a vertex of degree 3. But any two-dimensional symmetric convex body is a section of 3-dimensional body with a boundary which has a polyhedral part with a vertex of degree 3.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Nice comment.